# Insert new PHP array value using string key

Tags: php

I am able to create array values using

```
$array = array("key" => "value" ... );
```

Now I want to add them dynamically after assigning the value to $array

Comment: Have you read the PHP [documentation about arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing)?

Comment: @axiac thanks i saw the answer! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can access your array by using `[]` so

```
$array["new_key"] = "new value";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    42    => 24,
    "multi" => array(
         "dimensional" => array(
             "array" => "foo"
         )
    )
);

var_dump($array["foo"]);
var_dump($array[42]);
var_dump($array["multi"]["dimensional"]["array"]);
?>
```

This helps you. Refer the php documentation of arrays.